# Passing a buffer to picohttpparser results in compile error

Tags: c, http, parsing

I've been attempting to get [picohttpparser](https://github.com/h2o/picohttpparser) to work yet all my exertion is futile. What I'm endeavoring to begin with is basically passing a "manual" buffer to picohttpparser to parse it. This is the example from the official project page:

```
char buf[4096], *method, *path;
int pret, minor_version;
struct phr_header headers[100];
size_t buflen = 0, prevbuflen = 0, method_len, path_len, num_headers;
ssize_t rret;

while (1) {
    /* read the request */
    while ((rret = read(sock, buf + buflen, sizeof(buf) - buflen)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
        ;
    if (rret <= 0)
        return IOError;
    prevbuflen = buflen;
    buflen += rret;
    /* parse the request */
    num_headers = sizeof(headers) / sizeof(headers[0]);
    pret = phr_parse_request(buf, buflen, &method, &method_len, &path, &path_len,
                             &minor_version, headers, &num_headers, prevbuflen);
    if (pret > 0)
        break; /* successfully parsed the request */
    else if (pret == -1)
        return ParseError;
    /* request is incomplete, continue the loop */
    assert(pret == -2);
    if (buflen == sizeof(buf))
        return RequestIsTooLongError;
}

printf("request is %d bytes long\n", pret);
printf("method is %.*s\n", (int)method_len, method);
printf("path is %.*s\n", (int)path_len, path);
printf("HTTP version is 1.%d\n", minor_version);
printf("headers:\n");
for (i = 0; i != num_headers; ++i) {
    printf("%.*s: %.*s\n", (int)headers[i].name_len, headers[i].name,
           (int)headers[i].value_len, headers[i].value);
}
```

be that as it may, it's far excessively involved and I felt lost, so I started low by making a simple buffer to be passed to the parser with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "picohttpparser.h"



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* simple buffer */
    char rret[58]="GET /tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/ HTTP/1.1";

    /* parse the request */
    phr_parse_request(rret, 58, "GET", 3);

    return 0;
}
```

issue is I keep getting this error:

```
parsebuf.c: In function ‘main’:
parsebuf.c:14:33: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘phr_parse_request’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     phr_parse_request(rret, 58, "GET", 3);
                                 ^~~~~
In file included from parsebuf.c:4:0:
picohttpparser.h:53:5: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 int phr_parse_request(const char *buf, size_t len, const char **method, size_t *method_len, const char **path, size_t *path_len,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parsebuf.c:14:40: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘phr_parse_request’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     phr_parse_request(rret, 58, "GET", 3);
                                        ^
In file included from parsebuf.c:4:0:
picohttpparser.h:53:5: note: expected ‘size_t * {aka long unsigned int *}’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 int phr_parse_request(const char *buf, size_t len, const char **method, size_t *method_len, const char **path, size_t *path_len,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parsebuf.c:14:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘phr_parse_request’
     phr_parse_request(rret, 58, "GET", 3);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.c:4:0:
picohttpparser.h:53:5: note: declared here
 int phr_parse_request(const char *buf, size_t len, const char **method, size_t *method_len, const char **path, size_t *path_len,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

where could I be conceivably wrong? alternatively, are there more straightforward examples than the one on the project site?

Comment: Your call to `phr_parse_request` is wrong.

Comment: The third argument expects a `const char**`, you are passing an incompatible type (the error message is clear enough), because you are passing a `const char*`.

Answer (score 1):

I went to their github page and this is what they say before the code:

> The example below reads an HTTP request from socket `sock` using `read(2)`, parses it using `phr_parse_request`, and prints the details.

The function `phr_parse_request` parses a request made to the server, so it need
to write what kind of request (GET,POST,DELETE,etc), that's why the function
expects a `const char**`.

The functions looks like this:

```
int phr_parse_request(const char *buf_start, size_t len, const char **method, size_t *method_len, const char **path,
size_t *path_len, int *minor_version, struct phr_header *headers, size_t *num_headers, size_t last_len)
```

The arguments are all pointers, because `phr_parse_request` will change where
these variables (`method`, `path`) are pointing to, that's why you don't need to
initialize them or allocate memory for it.

So you have to declare the variables like they do in the example:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *method, *path;
    size_t buflen = 0, method_len, path_len, num_headers;
    struct phr_header headers[100];
    int pret, minor_version;

    char request[] = "GET /tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ....";

    num_headers = sizeof(headers) / sizeof(headers[0]);

    pret = phr_parse_request(request, strlen(request), &method, &method_len, &path, &path_len,
                             &minor_version, headers, &num_headers, 0);

    if(pret > 0)
    {
        // success
        // method has the request methid,
        // method_len the length of (I presume they don't write the 0
        // terminating byte
        // etc.
    }

    ...
}
```

The only thing I don't understand is the meaning of `prevbuflen`, which is used
as the last argument in the example. Sadly there is no documentation (or at
least I can't find one). But judging from the [`bench.c`](https://github.com/h2o/picohttpparser/blob/master/bench.c) file on the
repository, that value can be 0. Look at [that file](https://github.com/h2o/picohttpparser/blob/master/bench.c), that's the "quick &
dirty" example without having to write the networking support. Use that file for
your experiments.